# Zend2 initializer strange behavior

Tags: debugging, zend-framework2, protected

I am debugging Zend2 initializer and got strange behavior of `ServiceLocator`.

I have my `ViewManager` in protected `instance` variable:

[image]

After I step over `$this->serviceLocator->get` my protected variable `instance` is changed!

[image]

Now I get `FilterManager` in `$this->instance`. Yes, I passed string var `$class` with `FilterManager` to `ServiceLocator`. But how can this behavior even be possible to change protected variable `instance`?

Comment: Do you have active watches? Maybe you are changing the instance value at runtime this way.

Comment: No, I didn't used watches